# Something is triggering automount. I want to stop it

Tags: fedora, gnome, systemd-mount

I'm trying to figure out what is triggering some of my automounts. From what I can tell, every time I log in via GDM, I see some of my automounts mounted (which I don't want). My automounts are configured in /etc/fstab with:`x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=200` options.

What changed? I upgraded from Fedora 30 to 32. In an attempt to trouble shoot this, thinking maybe it was a bug in either systemd or gnome-shell, I upgraded again from 32 to 34. It did nothing to help.

Some things I did was to change the dconf of org > gnome > desktop > media-handling > automount to false, as well as created /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-media-automount with the following content:

```
[org/nome/desktop/media-handling]
automount=false
automount-open=false
```

I think it likely a Gnome problem, since if I log in via the console the issue doesn't occur. But I'm open to it being a systemd issue instead.

Comment: Ok, so by process of elimination, I found out that it has something to do with the dropbox daemon. I disabled dropbox starting at startup, logged out and in, and there ya go.

But my question persists. Why would Dropbox do this, if it's function is supposed to be restricted to my home directory.

Stay tuned as I complain to Dropbox...